# Regroup By in PigLatin

Tags: hadoop, group-by, apache-pig

In PigLatin, I want to group by 2 times, so as to select lines with 2 different laws.

I'm having trouble explaining the problem, so here is an example. Let's say I want to grab the specifications of the persons who have the nearest age as mine ($my_age) and have lot of money.

```
Relation A is four columns, (name, address, zipcode, age, money)

B = GROUP A BY (address, zipcode); # group by the address

-- generate the address, the person's age ...

C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, MIN($my_age - age) AS min_age, FLATTEN(A);

D = FILTER C BY min_age == age

--Then group by as to select the richest, group by fails :

E = GROUP D BY group; or E = GROUP D BY (address, zipcode);

-- The end would work
D = FOREACH E GENERATE group, MAX(money) AS max_money, FLATTEN(A);

F = FILTER C BY max_money == money;
```

I've tried to filter at the same time the nearest and the richest, but it doesn't work, because you can have richest people who are oldest as mine.

---

An another more realistic example is :

You have demands file like : iddem, idopedem, datedem

You have operations file like : idope,labelope,dateope,idoftheday,infope

I want to return operations that matches demands like :
idopedem matches ideope.

The dateope must be the nearest with datedem.

If datedem - date_ope > 0, then I must select the operation with the max(idoftheday), else I must select the operation with the min(idoftheday).

```
Relation A is 5 columns (idope,labelope,dateope,idoftheday,infope)
Relation B is 3 columns (iddem, idopedem, datedem)

C = JOIN A BY idope, B BY idopedem;

D = FOREACH E GENERATE iddem, idope, datedem, dateope, ABS(datedem - dateope) AS datedelta, idoftheday, infope;

E = GROUP C BY iddem;

F = FOREACH D GENERATE group, MIN(C.datedelta) AS deltamin, FLATTEN(D);

G = FILTER F BY deltamin == datedelta;

--Then I must group by another time as to select the min or max idoftheday
H = GROUP G BY group; --Does not work when dump
H = GROUP G BY iddem; --Does not work when dump

I = FOREACH H GENERATE group, (datedem - dateope >= 0 ? max(idoftheday) as idofdaysel : min(idoftheday) as idofdaysel), FLATTEN(D);

J = FILTER F BY idofdaysel == idoftheday;

DUMP J;
```

Data in the 2nd example (note date are already in Unix format) : 
You have demands file like :

```
1, 'ctr1', 1359460800000
2, 'ctr2', 1354363200000
```

You have operations file like :
idope,labelope,dateope,idoftheday,infope

```
'ctr0','toto',1359460800000,1,'blabla0'
'ctr0','tata',1359460800000,2,'blabla1'
'ctr1','toto',1359460800000,1,'blabla2'
'ctr1','tata',1359460800000,2,'blabla3'
'ctr2','toto',1359460800000,1,'blabla4'
'ctr2','tata',1359460800000,2,'blabla5'
'ctr3','toto',1359460800000,1,'blabla6'
'ctr3','tata',1359460800000,2,'blabla7'
```

Result must be like :

```
1, 'ctr1', 'tata',1359460800000,2,'blabla3'
2, 'ctr2', 'toto',1359460800000,1,'blabla4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample input and output would help greatly, but from what you have posted it appears to me that the problem is not so much in writing the Pig script but in specifying what exactly it is you hope to accomplish.  It's not clear to me why you're grouping at all.  What is the purpose of grouping by address, for example?

Here's how I would solve your problem:

First, design an optimization function that will induce an ordering on your dataset that reflects your own prioritization of money vs. age.  For example, to severely penalize large age differences but prefer more money with small ones, you could try:

```
scored = FOREACH A GENERATE *, money / POW(1+ABS($my_age-age)/10, 2) AS score;
ordered = ORDER scored BY score DESC;
top10 = LIMIT ordered 10;
```

That gives you the 10 best people according to your optimization function.

Then the only work is to design a function that matches your own judgments.  For example, in the function I chose, a person with $100,000 who is your age would be preferred to someone with $350,000 who is 10 years older (or younger).  But someone with $500,000 who is 20 years older or younger is preferred to someone your age with just $50,000.  If either of those don't fit your intuition, then modify the formula.  Likely a simple quadratic factor won't be sufficient.  But with a little experimentation you can hit upon something that works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is very interessant but It doesn't solve my problem. I will change the example.